# How to keep checking if a gameobject will be instantiated in hierarchy in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, instantiation

I want to keep checking whether a game object will be instantiated.All I have is the gameobject name say 'Model'.If model is active in hierarchy I want to do something.The problem is initially the gameobject is not available.Later only it will be instantiated.How to check whether the gameobject with name is present in hierarchy which will be a clone.

`if(gameobject.name=="Model(Clone)")
{
//Do something
}`

This will return a **null value** since it was not instantiated initially.After some time it will be instantiated.

Comment: If you could provide more information it would be easier to help you. Maybe more sample code around how do you instantiate the gameobject and where.

Comment: I instantiate a model when I touch on the screen.If that model which is a clone is active in hierarchy I want to do something.

Comment: Are the models created by a third party and this is why you only have access to the gameobject name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize variable Model
`Gameobject Model;`

The logic assertion will be returned false when Model is not yet instantiated

```
if (Model != null && Model.name == "Model(Clone)"){//return false
    //Do Something
}
```

Instantiate the gameobject with a name.
`Gameobject Model = Instantiate (somePrefab);`

The `if` needs to be placed inside `void update()`, or looping thing like `invoke()` which will constantly checking the condition.

It will check the if and return true when Gameobject Model is not null and there's gameobject named Model(Clone)

```
if (Model != null && Model.name == "Model(Clone)"){//return true
    //Do Something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If it was me I would do something like this.

```
List<GameObject> models = new List<GameObject>;
public GameObject baseModel; //Your model

private void CreateModel()
{
   GameObject obj = GameObject.Instantiate(baseModel) as GameObject;
   models.Add(obj);
}
```

that way you can use this.

```
void Update()
{
   if(models.Count > 0)
   {
       //Do Something
   }
}
```

remember if you are going to destroy the object don't forget to do this.

```
private void DestroyModel(GameObject obj)
{
   models.Remove(obj);
   Destroy(obj);
}
```

This is good practice to assign your GameObject somewhere. lol

Answer (score 1):

if you have an attribute "gameobject" in your code causing the code you provided to throw a null-exception, just do

```
if(gameobject!=null && gameobject.name=="Model(Clone)")
{
    //Do something
}
```

instead.

If you don't have access to that game object and you just want to detect if it exists yet, try something like

```
var go = GameObject.Find("Model(Clone)");
if(go!=null)
{
    //Do something
}
```

or if your game object has some script component MyScript, you can do

```
var gos = GameObject.FindObjectsOfType<MyScript>();
if(gos!=null && gos.Length > 0)
{
    // foreach(var go in gos) {}
    //Do something
}
```

Comment: the below statement will go null.Since the gameobject will be instantiated after sometime                                                                                
  var  go = GameObject.Find("Model(Clone)");

Comment: which is why there is a null-check, right...? "if(go!=null)"

Comment: I'd like to mention that even though this will work, searching the entire hierarchy for a gameobject is inefficient and should be avoided if possible. But it is still a viable solution when there is nothing else available.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet here is using UnityEvents.
Basically, when you want to run a piece of code, you just register it as a listener to a UnityEvent. So when you do something, say `Instantiate` an object, you can `Invoke` that UnityEvent immediately after, and it will run all the listeners that you registered to it, no matter where those pieces of code are in your project.

You first need to write the code that `Instantiates` the gameobject and `Invokes` the UnityEvent immediately after (this entire thing is in one .cs file, btw):

```
public class GameObjectSpawner : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public GameObject GameObjectPrefab;
    public GameObjectEvent OnCreateObject;

    private void Update() 
    {
        // Everytime you click your left mouse button
        // Only runs once per mouse click
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) 
        {
            // Instantiate the gameobject...
            GameObject go = Instantiate(GameObjectPrefab);

            // Then immediately Invoke our event to run all the listeners
            // and passing our gameobject to them.
            OnCreateObject.Invoke(go);
        }
    }
}

// This is just so the code that 'listens' to the event can get access to the 
// gameobject that just got instantiated.
public class GameObjectEvent : UnityEvent<GameObject> { }
```

So if you have a code somewhere else in your project that needs to run when that gameobject is `Instantiated`, that code runs ONLY when your gameobject is instantiated, never before (unless you manually run that code). Registering that code as a listener to the `OnCreateObject` event is as easy as this (this can be in a different .cs file):

```
public GameObjectSpawner Spawner;

private void Start()
{
    // You can place this anywhere you want to, but we're
    // placing this here in Start just to make sure that
    // we're already listening waaay before the gameobject
    // is instantiated.
    Spawner.AddListener(CheckHierarchy)
}

// It doesn't matter if this is public or private,
// as long as it's void and takes in a GameObject as a parameter.
private void CheckHierarchy(GameObject go)
{
    // Now we can do all kinds of things to the newly instantiated
    // gameobject, like check if it's active in the hierarchy!
    if (go.activeInHierarchy == true)
    {
        Debug.Log("I LIVE!!!");
    }
}
```

There's more to UnityEvents than this, but this is just the gist of it to help you start using it. Good luck!